# Angularjs http.delete is not working after deploying project on server

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.1

I am working  on a Laravel5.1 project. While working on localhost using xampp `http.delete` works fine but after hosting the project on remote server this delete option is not working though other properties are working fine. 
here is a portion of the code

```
$scope.removeSaleTemp = function(id) {
        $http.delete('api/saletemp/' + id).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $http.get('api/saletemp').success(function(data) {
                    $scope.saletemp = data;
                    });
            });
    }
```

'api/saletemp/' goes to SaleTempApiController

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    SaleTemp::destroy($id);
}
```

view part:

```
<tr ng-repeat="newsaletemp in saletemp">
                                <td>@{{newsaletemp.item_id}}</td><td>@{{newsaletemp.item.item_name}}</td><td>@{{newsaletemp.item.selling_price | currency}}</td><td><input type="text" style="text-align:center" autocomplete="off" name="quantity" ng-change="updateSaleTemp(newsaletemp)" ng-model="newsaletemp.quantity" size="2"></td><td>@{{newsaletemp.item.selling_price * newsaletemp.quantity | currency}}</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="removeSaleTemp(newsaletemp.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></td>
 </tr>
```

Note that , This code works fine on localhost (xampp) but fails after deploying in server.

Comment: are you using windows system ?

Comment: For developing purpose, yes.

Comment: Most probably it will be case sensitivity issue.  Make sure you are using same Case in angular part and your php part. `SaleTemp` and `saletemp` are different in unix system.

Comment: Just have refactor SaleTemp to satetemp as you told but didn't work. If Cascading is a problem then why other functions works properly?

Comment: what's the http response from the server? it might be a CORS issue

Comment: @vitr when I clicked the delete button nothing happens.

Comment: do you use devtools to see actual http commutations?

Comment: no, I didn't use any tools to check http communications.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are calling wrong url. I think you are trying to call www.example.com/api/saletemp/1. Instead you are calling www.example.com/something/api/saletemp/1 url. To make sure you are using the correct url put `$http.delete('/api/saletemp/' + id)`.

May be this will help.

Comment: HasiburRahmanOmi vai, if it's the problem in calling url then why it works on localhost ?

Comment: Localhost & remote server works in different way. Like: when you call localhost/project it will call your project. But if you call www.example.com/project then it will try to find the page

Answer (score 0):

Google a lot and find the solution.
Only I was needed to add the following permissions at .htaccess file in the root directory

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Limit>
<LimitExcept GET POST PUT DELETE HEAD OPTIONS>
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```